# Masm indirect addressing mode for MOV command

Tags: masm, addressing-mode

I've tried the following forms and masm doesn't like any of them:

```
mov byte [myVariable], al
mov byte ptr [myVariable], al
mov [byte myVariable], al
```

What am I missing? Why can't I seem to use indirect addressing.

the error I get from masm is 'Missing operator in expression" on some of the lines, some of them say "Structure field expected"

Answer (score 1):

```
myVariable equ 0404h
```

does not declare a variable, it declares a constant. The assembler simply replaces all constants with their values in the object file. Hence,

```
mov [myVariable], al
```

becomes

```
mov [0404h], al
```

which is invalid.

You have to assign the value to a register, like so:

```
mov di,0404h
mov byte ptr [di],al
```

Comment: You can use just an immediate as a base value. You can do it as ``mov [ds:myVariable], al` (specify whatever segment the base is relative to)

Answer (score 0):

```
mov [myVariable], al
```

should be sufficient, or even just:

```
mov myVariable, al
```

But then again
mov byte ptr [myVariable], al
should *also* work, which makes me wonder "what is 'myVariable'"?

Comment: it is an address that is declared at the top such as
myVariable equ 0404h.

then some of the calls are using registers with offsets such as 
bp+10

Comment: the indirect addressing isnt working for and either:

and [bp+22h], 77h   results in "Invalid instruction operands"

Comment: Changed it to mov ds:[myvariable], al

and got: "Invalid instruction operands"

Comment: That's really odd. Maybe you should create a really really tiny full example and show us?

Comment: here is a small test program:

.model tiny
.stack
.186
.code
myValue equ 03f6h 
myValue2 equ 0400h 

 mov bp,myValue 
 and [bp+18h],0feh 
 mov ds:[myValue2],1
 jmp [cs:testLabel]  
testLabel:
 nop
 nop
 jmp testLabel
 
 end


line 9&10: Invalid instruction operands

Comment: .186? That's new to me... have you tried without it? Now I'm just guessing wildly...

Comment: yea, here is the different processor instructions:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/47504

i need the .186 for some of the commands i'm using later. however i have tried without it and it doesnt affect the outcome

Comment: I think you got "invalid instruction operands" in your small test program because you can't move immediate to memory. (mov ds:[myValue2],1)  You have to go through a register.

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy : You can move an immediate to a memory operand. You do not have to go through a register. You may have to specify `word ptr` or `byte ptr` if the size can't be inferred.